# i need to adminLTE type menu effect

Tags: javascript, html, css

I design sidebar using css/html. its collapsible. when i click collapsible button, menu hide and show only icons. that moment, when user hover menu icon, menu should show as below image.

My design
[image]

but i need to do as below image (when mouse hover, menu should display)
[image]

can u do the small sample for do it

Answer (score 0):

You can try coreUI Bootstrap Admin free template. I think this will fulfill your requirements. Here is the URL of [coreUI template.](https://coreui.io/demo/#main.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution  I'm adding bootstrap and fontawesome for this solution. Chnages required for your own styling. Hope this solution works for you.

```css
  .btn-strip {
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background-color: black;
    color:white;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    transition: all 0.4s;
    cursor:pointer;
  }

  .menu-name {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  .btn-strip:hover {
    width: 200px;
  }

  .btn-strip:hover .menu-name {
    opacity: 1;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="container mt-4">
  <ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li class="btn-strip"> <i class="fa fa-home mr-2"></i>
      <span class="menu-name">Home</span></li>
    <li class="btn-strip"> <i class="fa fa-info mr-2"></i>
      <span class="menu-name">About</span></li>
    <li class="btn-strip"> <i class="fa fa-phone mr-2"></i>
      <span class="menu-name">Contact</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```